# How do I actively back up a folder to an external hard disk in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, backup, external-hard-drive, replication

I have an external hard disk I use for regular (manual) backup of my files.

How do I copy my files automatically to my hard disk?

Is there a built in way to do this through windows or do I have to use an third party program?

Comment: Have you looked at the File History feature in Windows 8? http://www.howtogeek.com/74623/how-to-use-the-new-file-history-feature-in-windows-8/

Comment: @DavidMarshall Yes, that's just about what I have been looking for. Thanks

Comment: BTW How is my question _not_ legitimate? Why did someone downvote this question?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this up here's my solution:

- As [@DavidMarshall](https://superuser.com/users/155943/david-marshall) pointed out the File History feature in Windows 8 is a great tool to let you backup your stuff and get revisions of them.

  He also added a link to a [nice tutorial explaining how to enable the File History feature](http://www.howtogeek.com/74623/how-to-use-the-new-file-history-feature-in-windows-8/).
- Another solution I came up with while googling was [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.sourceforge.net/) an open source freeware solution. It has the ability to save the job or schedule it to run automatically.